# Summation to infinity: $\sum_{r = n + 1}^\infty \frac{1}{r(r + 1)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

How would I get an answer for this, I know it's a telescopic series but I'm not sure how you can sum to infinity?
[image]

I have managed to get a formula in terms of $n$ as $1 + \left(\frac{1}{r(r + 1)}\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use partial fractions by writing:
$$ \frac 1{r(r+1)}= \frac 1r - \frac 1{r+1} $$

Hence, the partial sum can be written as:

$$ S_{m,n}= \sum_{r=n+1}^m \frac 1{r(r+1)} = \sum_{r=n+1}^m \frac 1r - \frac 1{r+1} \mathop{=}^{(\star)} \frac 1{n+1} - \frac1{m+1}. $$

where the equality $(\star)$ is shown by the telescoping sum property.

Take the limit $m \to \infty$, and you get the answer $\frac 1{n+1}$.

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $\dfrac{1}{r(r+1)} = \dfrac{1}{r} - \dfrac{1}{r+1}$

Comment: Yeah I kinda know that, but would I just sub in n+1 etc and then use as n--> infinity?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{1}{r(r+1)}
= \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}
$$
and
$$
S_N = \sum_{n+1}^N \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1} 
= 
\frac{1}{n+1} -
\frac{1}{N+1} \to \frac{1}{n+1} 
$$
for $N \to \infty$.